# Underscore extend method and fabric.js subclass

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, fabricjs

I've created an object that contains some common methods I will need across classes:

```
var PathBased = {
    appendPoint: function(point) {
            var lastPointIndex = this.getLastPointIndex();
            this.addPointAfterIndex(point, lastPointIndex);
    },

    getPointByIndex: function(index) {
            var pointX, pointY;

            if (index == 0) {
                    pointX = this.path[index][1];
                    pointY = this.path[index][2];
            } else {
                    pointX = this.path[index][3],
                    pointY = this.path[index][4];
            }

            return new fabric.Point(pointX, pointY);
    },

    ...

};
```

I would then like to create a fabric subclass that incorporates this functionality. I do that with the following code:

```
var Route = _.extend(fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Path, {
    initialize: function(path, options) {
        var options = options || {};
        this.app = options.app;
        this.model = options.model;

        options.stroke = options.stroke || this.app.config.routeStroke;
        options.fill = options.fill || this.app.config.routeFill;

        this.callSuper('initialize', path, options);

        _.bindAll(this, 'handleMoving');
        this.on('moving', this.handleMoving);
    },

    createRoutePoint: function(pointIndex) {
        var point = this.getPointByIndex(pointIndex);

        return new RoutePoint({
                top: point.y,
                left: point.x,
                pointIndex: pointIndex,
                route: this,
                app: this.app,
                model: this.model
        });
    },

        ...

}), PathBased);
```

After the page loads, in the Javascript console, I can see that if I create a new `Route` object: `var route = new Route`, that object does in fact have the methods from the `PathBased` object. For example, I can see that `route.getPointByIndex` exists.

However, as you can see above, the `Route` object has a method called `createRoutePoint`, which calls the `getPointByIndex` method from the `PathBased` object. When my program calls `route.createRoutePoint()`, I get an error that `getPointByIndex` is not defined.

Am I using the `extend` method incorrectly here? It seems like there is some sort of scope issue causing the `getPointByIndex` method not to be available from within the context of a `Route` object.

How do I do this correctly?

Comment: createClass should be returning a function (a constructor for the derived class).  It seems like you should be extending that function's prototype rather than the function itself.

Comment: Thank you. Can you show me a code example? I can't seem to get it to work. I tried separating things by first just calling `var Route = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Path, { //my Route stuff });`, and then on the next line calling `Route = _.extend(Route.prototype, PathBased);`, but doing that gives me an error when I try to create an instance of `Route` with `var route = new Route();` saying that `object is not a function`.

Comment: Yes, that's how I would do it, except don't assign the return value of `_.extend` back into `Route`, as that replaces `Route`'s constructor function with its prototype object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var Route = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Path, {
    ...
});
_.extend(Route.prototype, PathBased);
```

Explanation:

Route is a constructor function, so although it can have properties, those properties are not inherited by the Route instances you create with it. Those objects have Route.prototype as their prototype, so any properties added to Route.prototype are inherited by the instances.

Comment: Any chance you can explain why I'm extending `Route.prototype` instead of just `Route`?

Comment: Route is a constructor function, so although it can have properties, those properties are not inherited by the Route instances you create with it.  Those objects have Route.prototype as their prototype, so any properties added to Route.prototype are inherited by the instances.